# Writing CSV file into dataframe from FTPS server with python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get a csv file out of an ftps server. I am receiving this info, though:

```
file = r'filename.csv'

with ftplib.FTP() as ftp:
    
    with open(file, 'rb') as f: 
        ftp.retrbinary(file, f.read)
        df1= pd.read_csv(file)
        df1.head()
```

with this particular error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a2725f958d45> in <module>
      4 
      5     with open(file, 'rb') as f:
----> 6         ftp.retrbinary(file, f.read)
      7         df1= pd.read_csv(file) #delimiter = '|', encoding = 'latin1')
      8         df1.head()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py in retrbinary(self, cmd, callback, blocksize, rest)
    439           The response code.
    440         """
--> 441         self.voidcmd('TYPE I')
    442         with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
    443             while 1:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py in voidcmd(self, cmd)
    275     def voidcmd(self, cmd):
    276         """Send a command and expect a response beginning with '2'."""
--> 277         self.putcmd(cmd)
    278         return self.voidresp()
    279 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py in putcmd(self, line)
    197     def putcmd(self, line):
    198         if self.debugging: print('*cmd*', self.sanitize(line))
--> 199         self.putline(line)
    200 
    201     # Internal: return one line from the server, stripping CRLF.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\ftplib.py in putline(self, line)
    192         if self.debugging > 1:
    193             print('*put*', self.sanitize(line))
--> 194         self.sock.sendall(line.encode(self.encoding))
    195 
    196     # Internal: send one command to the server (through putline())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendall'
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't putting the requested file into a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary) says that the `cmd` argument of `retrbinary` method should be an appropriate RETR command: `RETR filename` and the `callback` function is called for each block of data received.

if you need to get data, write to file and read file try: `ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR {file}', f.write)`

Answer (score 0):

Method Name:
retrbinary

retrbinary(cmd, callback, blocksize=8192, rest=None)

`callback`:For each block of the data received from the FTP server the callback function is called. This callback function can be used for processing the data received. For example, the callback can be used for ***writing*** the received blocks into a file

for example:
you can use this:

```
fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
```

or

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % FILE, open(FILE, 'wb').write)
```

Comment: This still gives me the same error. Does this need any distinction of delimiters as well? Or a line by line write of the csv file into a dataframe?